# how to convert multiple vertical data to horizontal data from excel to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, excel

I have an excel generated from a system for daily sales and cost, but the data is in vertical format.
[image]

But I need to import this excel to my database in posrgresql in this format.

[image]

May I know how can I do this?? I really no idea on this part.